# Cannot load such file --mechanize

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mechanize, shoes

There is a class called ParseSearch.rb, which uses mechanize gem.

I made a new file that is used for Ruby Shoes(GUI) and I required all gems that are needed

```
require "mechanize"
require "rubygems"
require_relative "ParseSearch.rb"
```

In the terminal I installed the gem

```
$ gem install mechanize
Successfully installed mechanize-2.7.6
Parsing documentation for mechanize-2.7.6
Done installing documentation for mechanize after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

However, when I run the shoes.rb I get a error

```
Error in <unknown> line 0 | 2020-02-16 15:40:27 -0500
cannot load such file -- mechanize
.shoes/walkabout/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
.shoes/walkabout/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
search_shoes.rb:1:in `<main>'
.shoes/walkabout/lib/shoes.rb:353:in `eval'
.shoes/walkabout/lib/shoes.rb:353:in `visit'
.shoes/walkabout/lib/shoes.rb:139:in `show_selector'
.shoes/walkabout/lib/shoes.rb:169:in `block (4 levels) in splash'
```

The gem env are shown below.

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin
     - /.rbenv/libexec
     - /.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /.rbenv/shims
     - /.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

Comment: Are you using the same `ruby` in both cases?

Comment: It's possible that this installation of Shoes has its own Ruby which needs to have its own gems. The `gem` command you're using may be a whole other Ruby installation.

Comment: You don't need to `require "rubygems"` when using Ruby v1.9+.

Comment: What does `gem env` say? Copy, then paste its output into your question formatting it appropriately.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you for the help. I pasted the output.

Comment: You have (at least) two Ruby installations, one managed by rbenv, and another part of the Shoes environment. When you ran `gem install mechanize` I think the `gem` command was found in the Ruby in your path managed by rbenv, not in Shoes' embedded Ruby. To install it for Shoes you'll need to reference the `gem` command in the embedded Ruby explicitly, probably something like `<your path to shoes>/walkabout/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bin/gem`.